# Referencing Android custom library cause runtime class not found error in Application

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception

I am working on a custom Android library. I start off with a java project (in Eclipse) with another UI testing Android project.

In my UI testing project, I reference the library project in build path, and everything is good and I can test the library codes in the UI.

Later on, I decided I need to have the 'Gen' code (for custom styles attributes), so I try to change my library to an Android project (via Android-tools -> convert.. ), and disasters happens! After fixing up all the compile time problems, it finally 'let' me start the UI testing application, and bangs! When I try to create any objects from the library class, it said (in the Log) that **Class not found**.

Two questions:

1. Any idea how to fix this? I tried  but seems it is for referencing another .apk that need to install separately.
2. If I just keep it to be java project (not android) for my library, can I use the resource generator? and how?

PS: the dependency (my library) is installed before the UI test application, according to  the Console of Eclipse said.

Update: I tried to compile the library project to jar and reference it from the UI testing, and in this way, it works. But I don't want to use this approach since it is very slow in terms of testing.

Comment: @AlexLockwood I think this answer is what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11087994/818821

Answer (score -8, accepted):

Finally I found the answer to my own question. This is actually mentioned in [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html#libraryProject).

Comment: I had "-" on my projects name,i renamed the projects so now there is no "-" in the projects name,nut still R not get build,seems like classes which are not activity,service or receiver not get identified ,any help for this

Comment: @AlexLockwood did you read the link: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject

Comment: what are you talking about?

Comment: Yes, I read the link and am doing that.  Still the same error.  Also @xandy that link is dead, which is why stackoverflow recommends you post the relevant content and not the url.

Answer (score 1):

for those who are doing same mistake like me

when library project is an android project 
got to

> properties > android > click add button at bottom of the popup inside
>   library section

and add project, instead of

> properties > java build path > project > add

later approach is for pure java projects only .