# android instrumentation testing : IllegalAccessError

Tags: android, maven, instrumentation, buildpath

I am getting the IllegalAccessError while running Android instrumentation tests. 

This is Logcat output:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation
```

This is my setup: 

`TestProject` tests `UnderTestProject`, which includes `AnotherProject` in the buildpath (in 'Projects' tab), and exports it from 'Order and Export' tab. The class under test belongs to `AnotherProject`.

I have followed the suggestion in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431457/why-do-i-get-a-illegal-access-error-when-running-my-android-tests) here for configuring build path.

The builds are being done using Maven, from command line. `AnotherProject` is in the pom file for both `TestProject` and `UnderTestProject`, as dependency. Is this the reason for still getting the error? How can I fix this? Include `AnotherProject` in pom only for `UnderTestProject` and include `UnderTestProject` in the `TestProject`'s pom?

How does eclipse's build path tie up with maven's pom?

I am not clear about this, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

---

I tried the following, and still getting the problem:

1. Removed `AnotherProject` from `TestProject`'s pom, and added `UnderTestProject` to it.
2. Followed the advice on [this thread.](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20OpSys%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=142) My `UnderTestProject` doesn't even build if I add `<scope>provided</scope>` for `AnotherProject`.

I am stuck at this point, please let me know if you have a way out.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, follow the **Libraries** section on android-maven-plugin wiki page [here](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/AutomateAndroidTestProject):

> If your project set-up contains libraries then those too need to be added as <scope>provided</scope> otherwise they will be added to the test which will result in a duplication the error «Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation».
>
> ... ...
>
> Note Bug # 142, only Libraries with <packaging>jar</packaging> will work at this point.

Then right-click on your UnderTestProject, click Build Path -> Configure Build Path, tick Maven Dependencies in the Order and Export tab:[image]

This works for me, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have moved to Robolectric for now, and have got tests running. However, I have to get the instrumentation tests going, and I will verify this once I reach instrumentation again. I am accepting your answer till then.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. To fix it for me, I had to add the library dependencies in the main app's pom.xml to the test app's pom.xml, but add `<scope>provided</scope>` to them.

So if I have the following dependency in *MyApp* pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.nineoldandroids</groupId>
    <artifactId>library</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I had to add this to the *MyAppTest* pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.nineoldandroids</groupId>
    <artifactId>library</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify whether this is an Eclipse-only problem, or the project fails to build with Maven too (using the `android-maven-plugin`). In my case, both would fail. The reason: transitive dependencies from the `UnderTestProject.apk` would also find their way into `TestProject.apk` causing the `pre-verified` class problem. The solution for me was to apply this in my `TestProject`'s pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>UnderTestProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>apk</type>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>*</groupId>
            <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Using wildcards in this manner, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16354273/in-maven-how-can-i-exclude-all-transitive-dependencies-from-a-particular-depend), will produce a warning, but gets the job done beautifully (tested on `Maven 3.1.1`).