# had used a different Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity; during pre-verification: Android + Fragments + JUnit + Maven

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, junit, android-support-library

I've have two Android's project built with Maven under Eclipse. One is the project itself, and the other one a test project.

When I run the project as a `Android JUnit Test` it throws the error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception during suite construction
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.some.TestClass
```

Looking at `Logcat` I've found the root cause of this error that is:

```
Lcom.some.TestClass; had used a different Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity; during pre-verification
```

Digging on the web I'found a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5645277/1007772) with it solution was to remove the duplicated `android-support-v4.jar` from the test project. But this does not applies to Maven's projects due dependency inheritance.

The only way I found to get it work, was before launching I have to manually remove from the test project's build path the `Maven Dependencies` library and explicitly add a `Project Reference` to the target Android project.

¿Does anyone knows a way to get it work without this *hack*?

Here is a relevant fragment from my project's `pom.xml`:

```xml
<groupId>com.some</groupId>
<artifactId>project</artifactId>
<packaging>apk</packaging>
...
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

And the test project `pom.xml`:

```xml
<groupId>com.some</groupId>
<artifactId>project-test</artifactId>
<packaging>apk</packaging>
...
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.some</groupId>
        <artifactId>project</artifactId>
        <packaging>apk</packaging>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.some</groupId>
        <artifactId>project</artifactId>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently solved what seems to be the same problem. This is not specific to the `android-support-library`. Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20103673/1027527).