# maven dependency plugin - exclude transitive dependencies

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I work now on build for a huge project. It builds some big packages out of modules, that I need to unpack later to a folder. I use mvn dependency plugin for it. The issue that although I specify `<excludeTransitive>true</excludeTransitive>` I still see tons of modules that are downloaded from binary repo. Is there a clean solution to it?

Comment: It's generally a pain to block transitive dependencies in maven. There are different ways of doing it manually one dependency at a time, which is a lot of work for large projects, but haven't come across any simple flag that would allow it on a larger scale. If you do find something, would be interested to learn about it.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to build your individual modules without the transitive dependencies ?

Comment: I want to unpack an uber-jar/ear without resolving it's dependencies.

Comment: Maven 3.2.1 has a wildcard solution for this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16354273/in-maven-how-can-i-exclude-all-transitive-dependencies-from-a-particular-depend